# What are some simple NLP projects that a CS undergrad can try implementing?

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, computer-science

I dont know much about NLP.I need to do a NLP based compiler project as part of my course.My course instructor wants us to do a project based on a base paper. All the papers i look into seems complex. Pls help me by giving some ideas that are feasible and simple to implement.It would be great if you  suggest ideas based on a  conference paper

Comment: You have supervisors for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of them. Here is a list of different NLP problems:

- spam detection
- text genre categorization (news, fiction, science paper)
- finding similar texts (for example search for similar articles)
- find something about author (genre, native-speaker/non-native-speaker)
- create automatic grader for student's work
- check text for plagiarism
- create an application that looks for grammatical errors

Pretty much any conference paper can give an idea about an NLP project. For example you can think about [text summarization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_summarization), [lemmatisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation), tokenization, correct splitting text in sentences, etc.